# If $W$ is a subspace of vector space $V$, then $Span(W)=W$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

**My attempts**

$Span(W)=\{c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n|v_i\in W, c_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$, so every elements in $W$, exists in $Span(W)$ by taking relevant $c_i=1$ and the rest of $c_{j\neq i}=0$, hence $W\subseteq Span(W)$

For every element in $Span(W)$, must have the form $\sum_i^nc_iv_i$ and this satisfied the property of $W$ is a subspace, closed under addition and closed under multiplication, so whatever in $Span(W)$ exists in $W$, hence $Span(W)\subseteq W$.

---

${\color{red}{\text{I know that there are similar questions that have been asked on the web, but my question here is more specific.}}}$

**Q1** I am wobbling about my argument of $W\subseteq Span(W)$, I think the general idea is correct, but there is a flaw that comes in arguing this way.

Generally, the Span is defined over a collection of vectors, it contains all *finite* linear combinations of vectors with proper scale, we say those vectors span the vector space $W$.

However, when I say $Span(W)$ I am not sure if I can argue like $Span(W)=\{c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n|c_i\in\mathbb{R},v_i\in W\}$ because this is more like defined in terms of basis $\{v_i\}$, so it's fine to have finite terms $n$.

My intention is not to use basis, but every possible vector in $W$. Then the space $W$ may have infinite vectors, so my argument seems incorrect from the very beginning *(I am not sure)*. I need a more well-rounded, explicit argument to say $W\subseteq Span(W)$ rather than to say it coming from the definition. [see appendix, page 4](https://math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/Math344/Lectures/M344Lec02.pdf)

**Q2** Proving $Span(W)\subseteq W$, does it really have to be shown in an inductive way, is my argument sufficient?

Comment: The span is defined as the collection of finite linear combinations of elements of $W$. There is no need to invoke a basis. Alternatively, one may note that the intersection of an arbitrary number of linear subspace is again a linear subspace, and the span can be defined as the smallest subspace containing $W$.

Comment: To answer your question, if $w \in W$ then by definition $1 \cdot w \in \operatorname{span} W$.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree with your comments. If a collection of vectors spans $W$, the minimal(in terms of cardinality) set needs to be its basis, or **the set of finite linearly dependent vectors generated from the basis**. 

To be more precise with what I am trying to ask, what if $W$ spaned by such linearly dependent vectors denoted by set $P$ generated by basis, then one legitimate to claim $w\in W$ then by definition $1\cdot w\in Span(W)$ requires $w\in P$ isn't it?

Comment: @copper.hat then this argument seems not valid if $w\notin P$ explicitly, even $w$ can obtained by linear combination of vectors from $P$. If one argues that $P$ is collection of all vectors from $W$, then this also contradicts to *finite* linear combination if there are infinite vectors in $W$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of the meaning of the expression you wrote

$$Span(W)=\{c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n|c_i\in\mathbb{R},v_i\in W\}.$$

An element $w$ belongs to this set if and only if
$$ \exists n \in \mathbb N, \exists c_1,...,c_n \in \mathbb R, \exists v_1,...,v_n \in W : w = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i.$$

Note that this means that $n$, $v_1,...,v_n$ are not fixed !

However the way you are talking about this set it looks like you think that we have in advance picked a finite set of vectors $\{ v_1,...,v_n\}$ and that $Span W$ is the linear combinations of those vectors. The set of those linear combinations is the set

$$ \tilde W = \{  \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i v_i : c_i \in \mathbb R \}$$

and an element $w$ is in this set if and only if

$$ \exists c_1,...,c_n \in \mathbb R : w = \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i v_i.$$

In this case $n$ and $v_1,...,v_n$ are fixed in advance. This is not the same as the definition of the span of $W$.

To be more specific about what you wrote, consider this extract from your post:

> However, when I say $Span(W)$ I am not sure if I can argue like $Span(W)=\{c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n|c_i\in\mathbb{R},v_i\in W\}$.

There is nothing to argue here. This is the definition of the span.

---

In this way the proof becomes very easy.

$ W \subset span(W) ?$

Yes ! Let $w \in W$, take $n = 1$ and $v_1 = w$, $c_1 = 1$ and we have
$$ w = 1 \cdot w = c_1 \cdot v_1 \in Span(W)$$

$Span(W) \subset W  ?$

Yes, since $W$ is a subspace.

Comment: Thank you so much, extremely helpful, cleared up my misunderstanding.